# MySQL round up to next hundred (1-99 as 100)

Tags: mysql

I have tried round off but didn't work 
How to achieve in MySQL that
 if column value is 75 then output as 100
 if it is 105 as 200
 means 1-99 as 100 101-199 as 200 and so on.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote my quaetion? anyone

Answer (score 3):

For round up you can use [CEILING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) function.
for example:

```
SELECT CEILING(99/100) * 100;  -- 100
SELECT CEILING(101/100) * 100; -- 200
```

You can divide you number by 100 for get hundreds, round up hundreds using  CEILING function and multiply by 100 for get desired result

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FLOOR((your_number + 99) / 100) * 100;
-- 100
```